# Where should i put onItemClick for my ListView according to my code and how to parse object from getItemsOnPosition() to array?

Tags: java, android

I want to set onItemClick for my ListView, where should i put it in my code? One more, how to parse Object from getItemsOnPosition() to string array "name" and "errands"? Thanks.
I don't use list view items layout, just this and a layout for the ListView. Thanks

```
public class ErrandsFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_errands, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new ListTask().execute();
}

class ListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Retrieving Datas");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        WebService service = new WebService("My JSON", "GET", "");
        String jsonString = service.responseBody;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albums = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String name= object.getString("name");
                String errands= object.getString("errands");
                HashMap<String, String> album = new HashMap<>();
                album.put("name", name);
                album.put("errands", errands);
                albums.add(album);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return albums;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albums) {
        super.onPostExecute(albums);

        progressDialog.hide();
        ListView listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.errands_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                albums,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[] {
                        "name",
                        "errands"
                },
                new int[] {
                        android.R.id.text1,
                        android.R.id.text2
                }
        ));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the onPostExecute() method

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albums) {
        super.onPostExecute(albums);

        progressDialog.hide();
        ListView listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.errands_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                albums,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[] {
                        "name",
                        "errands"
                },
                new int[] {
                        android.R.id.text1,
                        android.R.id.text2
                }
        ));
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()"item clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }
```